# I want to replace fragment but its add after previous fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to replace fragment but android app add new fragment after first fragment instead of replace fragment. And after that when i try to replace again app replace with fragment which one is added after first fragment. First fragment which was loaded on activity, remain static. Can any body help? I am using this code to replace fragment.

```
Fragment fr = fragment;
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.frgRemote, fr);
ft.commit();

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.cerad.home.automation.RoomsActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lytHeader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/lytCamcontroller"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvHeading"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/stream_image"
            android:layout_width="640px"
            android:layout_height="480px"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
         android:contentDescription="@string/image_descriptor_video_streaming" />
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@id/lytCommandnControl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >


                <fragment
                    android:id="@+id/frgRemote"
                    android:name="com.cerad.automation.DefaultRemoteFragment"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btnTVRemote"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="@string/button_tv_remote" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btnDefault"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:checked="true"
                        android:text="@string/button_default_control" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btnACRemote"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="@string/button_ac_remote" />
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: How is the first fragment added? If it is done in code, please show the code. Initial suggestion would be to *always* use explicit tags when trying to replace fragments.

Comment: first fragment is add with xml                <fragment
                    android:id="@+id/frgRemote"
                    android:name="com.cerad.automation.DefaultRemoteFragment"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

Comment: you see the fragment in xml

Answer (score 0):

You might want to re-read the documentation for [`FragmentTransaction.replace()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace%28int,%20android.app.Fragment%29):

The first argument to `replace(int containerViewId, Fragment fragment)` is not the ID of the fragment's view, but the **ID of the container** of the fragment. Hence your call adds a new nested fragment (of the same type) inside the fragment view wrapper of the already existing fragment.

From [`FragmentTransaction.replace(id, frag, tag)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace%28int,%20android.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String%29)'s documentation:

> This is essentially the same as calling remove(Fragment) for all currently added fragments that were added with the same containerViewId and then add(int, Fragment, String) with the same arguments given here.

To fix this, you must give an ID to the `LinearLayout` containing your fragment, e.g.

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
```

and call `replace()` with the ID of the container.

```
ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fr);
```

It is also good practice to always assign unique tags to pre-defined fragments:

```
           <fragment
                android:id="@+id/frgRemote"
                android:name="com.cerad.automation.DefaultRemoteFragment"
                android:tag="remote_fragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

So that you can address multiple fragments by their unique tags, if necessary

```
ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fr, "remote_fragment");
```

Answer (score 0):

I have three fragments, i replace like this:

```
private void displayView(int position) {

        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new HomeFragment();

            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new AlterFragment();
            break;

        case 2:
            fragment = new ExtraFragment();
            break;


        default:
            break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();


            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        }
        else {

        }
    }
```